# Images not showing in RDLC on one PC only

Tags: c#, image, rdlc

I have a **RDLC** report with some images, this images are embedded externally with the absolute path

```
file://\\srv10\M\Images\Image.jpg
```

The images are loaded fine except for one PC where it just load an error image (a red cross).

I tried everything but I can't figure it out, I can reach the image on that PC with no problem. This images are also loaded in the C# application that generate the report with no problem on that PC, they're just not showing in **RDLC**.